# How can I send email over gprs?

Tags: email, gprs

How can I send email over gprs from a mobile device under Windows Mobile 6.x to a server (connected to ... whatever, if email can be sent/received).

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to an SMTP server. Typically the GPRS provider will have one you can use.  If you want to be truly independent, then set up your own SMTP server, or use somebody else's.   Watch out, because some GPRS providers will block port 25, to reduce spam.

One option is to set up some kind of proxy.  Say a php page on your web server that your app connects to, and sends the e-mail for you.  Just make sure it's secure.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the PocketOutlook namespace and specifically to the [EmailMessage.Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.emailmessage.send.aspx) method.

Comment: I knew that, just wanted to know the relationship with Connection Manager. Thanks